Transition on navbar in bootstrap not working
I'm having an issue with Bootstrap transitions not working properly on my navbar. Here's what I'm experiencing:
When I click the dropdown button in the navbar, the hidden elements appear, but there's no transition effect.
Here's the HTML code I'm using:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



I'm using Bootstrap version 5.2.3, as indicated in the CDN links.
Expected behavior: When clicking the navbar toggle button, the collapsible content should appear with a smooth transition effect.
Actual behavior: The content appears instantly without any transition effect.
I've tried this in multiple browsers, but the result is the same. There are no error messages in the console.
What could be causing the transitions to not work, and how can I fix this issue?

as you can see in runnable code snippet, your code works fine. so, add the code that reproduces the problem you describe

Is it possible your system is set to prefers-reduced-motion? Having Show animations in Windows disabled on a Windows system would cause transitions to not be shown. It's part of Bootstrap's support for accessibility.

I tried your code, it works with a smooth transition effect.
